# Perform a local execution, by remotely invoke command

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, powershell

Successfully managed to PowerShell over SSH, using [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-6).
Now, I want to invoke a command remotely from Linux server, so the execution will be locally on the Windows server.

For example:

Linux machine:

```
$s = new-PSSession -HostName WinHost -UserName user
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {C:\scripts\boo.ps1}
```

boo.ps1 script(just for the example):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Hello')
```

Expected:

- MessageBox will appear in the Windows machine screen

Reality:

- Trying to execute it in the local Linux shell, What failed of course, because it is not suitable to run on Linux prompt.

Tried to run it with another `.bat` file, so it will call `.ps1` script, same result.

Comment: this will give you a lot of pain. I know some commands are restricted in a Remote PowerShell session, so depending on your commands you want to execute on the RemoteSystem, you will either not be able to use them at all, or have to make a lot of adjustments to get this working. A Messagebox for example needs to run in UserInteractive Mode or as a ServiceNotification or on DefaultDesktopOnly. So depending on what you're trying to do, it will give you many headaches. If I run your command exactly the way you did, the errormessage I get comes from MessageBox, not from the local shell

Comment: That being said, I would workaround this issue by creating Scheduled Tasks on the RemoteSystem which execute your scripts, and trigger them via `Invoke-Command` or even better, via `CimSession`

Comment: The goal is to execute PowerShell script that uses Workflows functions, via Jenkins server. Since, PScore doesn't support Workflows, I did the workaround as described in the question.